# Replace substrings by html elements inside a paragraph without messing with occurrences using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

My purpose is to change each words color in a paragraph, smoothy and one by one.

It works but the substrings occurrences make it crash.
I'm not really good in javascript, but this is what I'v done so far:

```
// GET WORDS LIST
var pText = $('p').text(); //Get the text of the concerned element
var pArray = pText.split(/\s/g); //Transform the string in an array

//Put values in a clean new array without spaces
var pClean = new Array();
var j = 0; 
for (var i = 0; i < pArray.length; i++) {
  if(pArray[i] != ''){
    pClean[j] = pArray[i];
    j++;
  }
}
var pArray = []; //Delete the old one


//WRAP AND REPLACE WORDS
var i = 0;
setInterval( function () {

  //stop the loop
  if(pClean[i] == ''){
  // I don't really ge how to use clearInterval for stopping the loop.
  }

  //replace words
  if($('p').text().indexOf(pClean[i])){

    $('p:contains("'+pClean[i]+'")').html(function(_, html) {
      var replacement = '<span class="read">'+pClean[i]+'</span>';
      return  html.replace(pClean[i], replacement);
    });

    $('p .read:last').addClass('hlight'); //highlight the last
  }

  i++;
}, 300);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qr7b3hjn/4/).

It must be a better way to do this...
Thanks for your time!

### Edit -----

I applied the code of the validated answer it works really well, but I also tried to add exceptions in the append function without any success. It seems to not detect the this var.

```js
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    if(this == '4.'){
        $(p).append($('<br><span>'+v+'</span>'));
    }
    else {
        $(p).append($("<span>").text(v)).append(" ");
    }
});

//WRAP AND REPLACE WORDS
var i = 0;
setInterval( function () {
    //stop the loop
    if($('p :not(.read):first').length == 0){
    }
     $('p :not(.read):first').addClass("read");
    //$("p .read").removeClass("hlight");
    $("p .read:last").addClass("hlight");
}, 500);
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What about if you do this, you start with spans around each word, then you can just add the classes one by one.

```js
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    $("p").append($("<span>").text(v)).append(" ");
});

//WRAP AND REPLACE WORDS
var i = 0;
setInterval( function () {
    //stop the loop
    if($('p :not(.read):first').length == 0){
 }
     $('p :not(.read):first').addClass("read");
    //$("p .read").removeClass("hlight");
    $("p .read:last").addClass("hlight");
}, 500);
```

```css
p{
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
}

p .read{
    color: black;
    transition: color 1s ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

p .read.hlight{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  
    Vestibulum dignissim, nisl nec laoreet hendrerit, tellus eros 
    tristique tortor, eu commodo nunc sem id erat. Aliquam erat 
    volutpat. Praesent ultrices quam justo, nec condimentum elit 
    imperdiet at. Duis a fringilla quam. Suspendisse condimentum 
    gravida volutpat.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shriike, it's simpler and it works perfectly. I'll try to add an if statement (for few exceptions) and I'll tell you what. Thanks again!